# Non-isomorphic $\mathbb{C}$-algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, self-learning

The question is as follows:

Show that the $\mathbb{C}$-algebras: $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2y-xy)$, $B=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2y+xy^2)$, $C=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy, yz, zx)$, and $D=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2y+xy^2+x^4+y^4)$ are pairwise non-isomorphic.

Is there a particularly elegant way to approach this? I've tried playing around with decompositions, but I can't quite get things to work. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**STRONG HINTS**

Look at how the algebraic sets decompose. The variety corresponding to $A$ is the union of three lines intersection in two points. It looks like this $\rightarrow  \coprod$, because $(x^2y-xy)=(x) \cap (y) \cap(x-1)$.

The second decomposes as $(x) \cap (x+y) \cap (y)$, so the algebraic set again consists of three lines, but this time they intersect in three points, forming a "fan" of three lines.

Similarly, $C$ is the union of the coordinate axes, so they intersect in one point.

And the fourth equation is irreducible, so $D$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Dear @Frederik, the second variety consists of the union of three lines through the origin. There is no  triangle in sight. so you have given no indication that $B$ and $C$ are non isomorphic. Nice answer though,  because you mention geometry: +1.

Comment: Would computing respective dimensions here be a viable strategy as well? Namely, using: $\mathrm{dim}(A/\mathfrak{p})+\mathrm{ht}(\mathfrak{p})=\mathrm{dim}(A)$ for $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $A$.

Comment: Here's an elaboration: you should be able to see that $V=V(x^2y-xy)$ is a variety of three lines either from the above or from $x^2y-y=0$. These lines intersect at two singular points. A clue that $V\ncong V(x^2y+xy^2)$ is that their numbers of singular points differ. Note as well that $D$ is an integral domain implies its variety is irreducible. I'll leave showing $B\ncong C$ to you. I'm not sure what other details you might want.